# formato en fechas python

Tags: python

Tengo una función que debo pasar a formato fecha y no logro realizarlo.
Esta es mi función y les muestro el error que me arroja:

```
def dateBir(self):
    if self.data['fecha_nac_dia'] != None and self.data['fecha_nac_dia'] != '' and self.data['fecha_nac_mes'] != None and self.data['fecha_nac_mes'] != '' and self.data['fecha_nac_agno'] != None and self.data['fecha_nac_agno'] != '':
        self.data['dob'] = str(self.data['fecha_nac_dia'])+'-' + str(self.data['fecha_nac_mes'])+'-' + str(self.data['fecha_nac_agno'])
    else:
        self.data['dob'] = None
```

El error que arroja es:

```
psycopg2.errors.DatetimeFieldOverflow: date/time field value out of range: "27-3-1962"
    LINE 1: ...'', '12345678', '12345678', '12345678', 'a@a.cl', '27-3-1962...
                                                                 ^
    HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
```

Comment: Ese código python no va a funcionar porque está mal indentado. Si bajo un if hay una línea al mismo nivel, no hay if. Por favor, revisa y ve a [edit] tu pregunta con código válido

Comment: El error parece ser de PostgreSQL, pero ni tu código ni tus etiquetas indican que uses dicha base de datos. Si es el caso, sería mejor que lo aclares.

Comment: No está relacionado con tu pregunta pero quizás en vez de `if self.data['fecha_nac_dia'] != None and self.data['fecha_nac_dia'] != '':` prefieras escribir `if self.data['fecha_nac_dia']:`.

Comment: Sin saber nada de PostgreSQL, te sugiero que pruebes pasando "**1962-03-27**", si es una burrada me disculpo ;)

Answer (score 0):

El error que estás enfrentando indica que el valor de fecha "27-3-1962" está fuera del rango válido para el campo de fecha/hora. Parece que estás utilizando una base de datos PostgreSQL y el formato de fecha esperado es diferente al que estás proporcionando.

Para solucionar este error, puedes utilizar la función datetime del módulo datetime de Python para manipular y formatear correctamente la fecha. Aquí hay una posible solución:

```
from datetime import datetime

def dateBir(self):
    if self.data['fecha_nac_dia'] and self.data['fecha_nac_mes'] and self.data['fecha_nac_agno']:
        try:
            day = int(self.data['fecha_nac_dia'])
            month = int(self.data['fecha_nac_mes'])
            year = int(self.data['fecha_nac_agno'])
            self.data['dob'] = datetime(year, month, day).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
        except ValueError:
            self.data['dob'] = None
    else:
        self.data['dob'] = None
```

En esta solución, se utiliza la función datetime para crear un objeto de fecha a partir de los componentes de día, mes y año que tienes en self.data. Luego, se utiliza strftime('%d-%m-%Y') para formatear la fecha como una cadena en el formato deseado (por ejemplo, "27-03-1962").

Recuerda importar el módulo datetime al principio de tu archivo si aún no lo has hecho.

Espero que esta solución resuelva tu problema con el error de formato de fecha.

Comment: Asegúrate de [no utilizar ChatGPT](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5462): está prohibido aquí.